# Render div in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to learn Vue's `render()` function to make the page components. Currently I have this and it works:

```
function createDiv (h, msg) {
  return h('div', msg)
}

new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data () {
    return {
      text: ''
    }
  },
  render (h) {  
    return createDiv(h, 'msg')
  }
})
```

But when I change the `render()` content to:

```
  render (h) {
    const arrSample = ['Hey', 'Hi', 'There']
    
    arrSample.forEach(msg => {
      return createDiv(h, msg)
    })
  }
```

then it doesn't render anything anymore.

Can anyone help shed some light on this?

Here is a sample codepen:
https://codepen.io/keechan/pen/vYyVGrR

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The trouble is that you don't return anything from your `render` function. You are just creating `div`'s `VNode`. You need to return something
2. Try this:

```
render(h) {
  const arrSample = ['Hey', 'Hi', 'There']

// map returns your data wrapped by div
  const list = arrSample.map(msg => {
    return createDiv(h, msg)
  })

// reason why we render the list in wrapped div is because
// you should return a single root node from `render` function.
  return createDiv(h, list)
}
```

3. [Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/Adam_Orlov/pen/KKNGzjp?editors=1010)